# In Entity Framework 6 I can't get my database initializer to execute?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am out of ideas. Googled it, but still can't figure out why my database initializer does not fire. I have MyDbContext class and MyDbContextInitializer class. In the Application_Start (using MVC4) I do this:

```
// Initialize database
Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbContextInitializer());
MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();
context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

I was working fine in EF 5, but when I switch to EF6, my Seed() in the MyDbContextInitializer class is never called. Why?

MyDbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("Name=MyDbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleConfig());
    }
}
```

MyDbContextInitializer:

```
public class MyDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        var roles = new List<Role>
        {
            new Role {Name = "Administrator"},
            new Role {Name = "User"}
        };

        roles.ForEach(r => context.Roles.Add(r));

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if any exceptions occur before initialization is even coming up?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I don't get any exceptions. Everything seems to be fine during run.

Comment: try this line of code {Database.SetInitializer<UserDbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>());}

Answer (score 0):

What does your connection string look like? If your connection string is set up a certain way the EF thinks you use Database first and will not fire the initialize methods.